# Angular 2 google map implementation

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular, angular2-template

I'm new to angular 2. I wanted to use google map API for direction service and implemented the example shown in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple to my project as shown below code. 
But for some reason the map is not loading. Can someone help me with this?

**map.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Directions service</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 500px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 500px;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>        
    <div id="floating-panel">
    <b>Start: </b>
    <select id="start">
      <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
      <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
      <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
      <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
      <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
      <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
      <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
      <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
      <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
      <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
      <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
      <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
    </select>
    <b>End: </b>
    <select id="end">
      <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
      <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
      <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
      <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
      <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
      <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
      <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
      <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
      <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
      <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
      <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
      <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 7,
          center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        var onChangeHandler = function() {
          calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        };
        document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
        document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
      }

      function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        directionsService.route({
          origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
          destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY-KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**MapComponent**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'map',
    templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/features/map.html'
}) 

export class MapComponent {}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found a solution for this.

1) Add google map api script in index.html

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[YOUR-KEY]" async defer></script>
```

2) Add only html related code in your html file.

**map.html**

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

3) Add style related codes in separate css file or in component.

**map.css**

```
      #map {
        height: 500px;
      }
```

4) Declare google as variable. And add all javascript in ngOnInit() method.

**MapComponent.ts**

```
declare var google: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'map',
    templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/features/map.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/dashboard/features/map.css']
}) 

export class MapComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

ngOnInit() {

        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
       var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 7,
          center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);

      function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {

          var waypts = [];
          var checkboxArray:any[] = [
              'winnipeg', 'regina','calgary'
      ];
      for (var i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {

            waypts.push({
              location: checkboxArray[i],
              stopover: true
            });

        }

        directionsService.route({
          origin: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65},
          destination: {lat: 49.3, lng: -123.12},
          waypoints: waypts,
          optimizeWaypoints: true,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      }

    }
```