# angular2-google-maps doesn't display markers from json

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular, google-maps-markers

I'm new to Angular2 but I've been trying to implement an app that - by using Google Maps - shows the position of some markers established by the user.
After having done some researches it seems that [angular2-google-maps](https://angular-maps.com/) component it's the most used solution.

My issue is the following: I'm not able to display any marker when those are got from an implemented service which gets a .json file containing the coordinates.

Many thanks in advance for helping me out.

**CODE**

**Template**

```html
<sebm-google-map 
     [latitude]="0" 
     [longitude]="0" 
     [zoom]="5">
            <sebm-google-map-marker  
             *ngFor="let location of locations; let i = index "
             [latitude]="location.address.geo.lat" 
             [longitude]="location.address.geo.lng">
            </sebm-google-map-marker>
    </sebm-google-map>
```

**Component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleMapService } from '../../services/google-map/google-map.service';

    @Component({ 
       selector: 'app-google-map',
       templateUrl: './google-map.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./google-map.component.css'],
       providers: [GoogleMapService]
    })
    export class GoogleMapComponent implements OnInit {
     locations: Location[];
       
       constructor(private googleMapService: GoogleMapService) { 
        
       }

       ngOnInit() {
        this.googleMapService.getLocations().subscribe(data => {
       this.locations = data;
       console.log('init');
      });
       }

    }

    interface Location {
     id: number;
     name: string;
     address: {
      geo: {
       lat: number,
       lng: number
      }
     };
    }
```

**Service**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class GoogleMapService {

   constructor(private http: Http) { 
    console.log('Locations service started...');
  }
  
   getLocations() {
  return this.http.get('locations.json')
   .map(res => res.json());
 }
}
```

**Json**:

```js
[
 {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Napoli",
    "address": {
        "geo": {
            "lat": "14.1065184",
            "lng": "40.8539009"
         }
     }
 },
 {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Barcelona",
    "address": {
        "geo": {
            "lat": "2.0787281",
            "lng": "41.3947688"
         }
     }
 }
]
```

Comment: I followed this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879993/angular-2-google-map-implementation
so even if I'm not using that solution anymore, the one suggested in this post seems working pretty fine.